# Why is the 'in' connector giving me wrong values?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a simple data analysis using pandas, and I want to check if the number of the circle that is being draw is in the data or not. The variable data is a pandas dataframe, here I'm just using the 'DayCount' column. The complete csv file and python script can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/lucasjoviniano/af1e9453c73fbdf4bb0bd40530c279a5)

```py
    cont = 1

    for i in range(1, 21):
        for j in range(1, 19):
            if cont in data['DayCount']:
                p = mpatches.Circle((i, j), 0.5, color='#01770b')
            else:
                p = mpatches.Circle((i, j), 0.5)
            ax.add_patch(p)
            cont += 1
```

The if condition should only be true for big numbers (the minimum value is 209) but it's being triggered by small values, expecifically: 1 to 49. So, It's coloring the circles 1 to 49, but not the ones that actually are in the data.

Comment: use `print()` to check values in variables. Or create minimal working code with your problem so we could run it and see problem.

Comment: Are you talking about the two `for n in range` statements, or the `cont in data` statement?  If it's the latter, we can't help without knowing what `data['DayCount']` is.

Comment: @JohnGordon just added more information - the csv file and the entire code. The problem is in the `cont in data` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `values` with `in`, this should be your `if` condition:

```
if cont in data['DayCount'].values
```

Comment: Closer, but still not a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turn data['Day Count'] into a list, otherwise it's getting confused with the indices of a dataframe slice:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    for j in range(1, 19):
        if cont in list(data['DayCount']):
            print(cont)
            p = mpatches.Circle((i, j), 0.5, color='#01770b')
        else:
            p = mpatches.Circle((i, j), 0.5)
        ax.add_patch(p)
        cont += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to give a condition to evaluate for a if statement. Example `if cont in data['DayCount'] > 209` or `if cont in data['DayCount'] < 209` something like that. THe way you have given now, 'if' is not checking anything.